# Invisible ink on Shabbat and Yom tov

Tags: shabbat, writing-printing, contemporary-halacha, responsa

I wanted to know if one could use invisible ink on shabbat or Yom Tov? I know writing is melacha, but what about invisible ink? Is there a responsa on this? Could one write with it on Shabbos to read (with ultraviolet light) after shabbat?

Comment: Related to [this comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26970/is-it-permitted-to-use-a-thermochromic-cup-on-shabbos#comment190220_26998) and [this comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26970/is-it-permitted-to-use-a-thermochromic-cup-on-shabbos#comment190224_26998).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R Yirmiyohu Kaganoff answers your question [here](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/20615)

> **There is no Torah violation in writing with ink that will disappear
> within a few hours.** This halacha has major ramifications when dealing
> with the needs of a Jewish hospital. Recording data is necessary, but
> if disappearing ink is used until after Shabbos, **the prohibition is
> only mi-derabbanan**. Poskim rely on this, if a hospital cannot employ
> sufficient non-Jewish staff.

Note this can only be relied on in case of great need, which is why he mentions hospitals.

Of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Comment: Invisible ink is not disapearing ink